# serve static assets with webpack

Tags: webpack, static, assets, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to serve static assets from webpack, but am right now using the copywebpack plugin to copy any desired static assets into my static_dist/ directory, which is also where my build files go. While this hack works, I now also need to serve stats file that is generated after the build process, stats.json. I cannot hack this and use copywebpackplugin, because this file does not yet exist when the copywebpackplugin runs. I am a bit overwhelmed by all of webpacks configuration options, and nothing seems to work for serving these static files.

// my webpack.config.js

```
const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, '../src/static'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, '../src/static_dist')
};

const basePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/static/');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: PATHS.build,
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            ignored: /node_modules/,
            poll: 1000,
        },
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: '/static/',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        disableHostCheck: true,
        historyApiFallback: { index: '/static/index.html' },
        public: 'localhost:8000',
        writeToDisk: true,
       // hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
          new CopyPlugin([
          { from: '../static/assets/img/favicons', to: '../static_dist/favicons' },

          { from: '../static/assets/img/logos', to: '../static_dist/logos' },
          { from: '../static/assets/img/icons', to: '../static_dist/icons'},
        ]),
        new BundleTracker({ path: PATHS.build, filename: './stats/webpack-stats.json'})
    ],
}
```

Right now, my bundles are accessed at `domain.com/static/app.[some-hash].js` and logos, for example, are accessed at `domain.com/static/logos/somelogo.png`. It appears most people do not have these served from the same directory, but I don't particularly care where they are served from. Just that I can serve the stats file which is generated after the build.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to wait until webpack compile is done. You can write your own plugin using a [webpack compiler-hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/). This is an example script. Untestet!

[compiler-hook aftercompile](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#aftercompile)

```
// fs-extra to copy files (npm install fs-extra)
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

// own plugin: do what ever 
class MyPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.afterCompile.tap('MyPlugin', (compilation) => {
            // copy all files and folder (recursive)
            fs.copySync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'static/assets/img/favicons'), path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'static_dist/favicons'), { recursive: true })
            // return true to emit the output, otherwise false
            return true;
        });
    }
};

//...

// append your plugin to webpacks plugin section
plugins: [
    //...
    new MyPlugin(),
    //...
]
```